# Angular 2 ngrx reducers : can not read property concat() of undefined?

Tags: arrays, angular, redux, ngrx

In my Angular2 application i have a reducer for adding replays to a comment :

**Replays.reducer.ts :**

```
 case ADD_REPLAY:
    let index_replay = state
      .map(review => review.id)
      .indexOf(action.payload.replayTo);
    return [
      ...state.slice(0, index_replay),
      Object.assign({}, state[index_replay], {
        replays: [...state[index_replay].replays, action.payload]
      }),
      ...state.slice(index + 1)
    ];

  default:
    return state;

}
```

When a comment already contain replays, i can add replay whithout problem, but when the replays array which is in the comment array is empty, i have error : can not read property concat of undefined (probably due to the spread operator).

How can i avoid this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling .concat on an empty array (spread operator === .concat) and thus you are getting the undefined error.

Try this:

`const replays = state.index_replay ? : state.index_replay : [];`

This assigns either `state.index_replay` or an empty array to replays.

Next, use the `replays` array in your spread operator.